# Building a GPS-controlled Camera

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, gps, tinygps

I've been trying to build an Arduino UNO controlled Camera using two servo motors that points in the direction of an object with a certain tag.

Here's an Example: A camera is on the sideline of a gym, and the players are running around. One player has a portable GPS piece attached to him, and the camera should point in the player's direction in order to capture the player's movements along with his background.

A few questions:
Would I use two different compasses in order to both record the direction and point the camera in this direction? Or would I use a GPS for the player and somehow convert the streaming data into compass direction(in which the camera will point)?

In a way, what combination (Player-Camera) would I use (if I need a combination), a GPS-GPS, GPS-compass, or compass-compass?

Do I actually need two location devices or just one?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: You should be aware of the accuracy of GPS, especially indoors. For consumer-grade products, it may not be enough for this project.

Comment: I agree with @Sanchises, unless you are going for a wide photo the resolution of GPS is about 10m.  You might be better using multiple directional radio signal sensors and triangulating the position, or if you have a camera with auto focus and no intervening objects you might be able to get a way with one directional radio sensor.  In either case you would need to do some reflection processing to cancel out the signal on the player bouncing off the gym walls.  Might it be better to look at the Pixy cam and visually track the 'player'?

Comment: A compass would be useless on the player. Whether the player is face towards or away from the camera, the camera should point in the same direction in either case.

Comment: you probably may want to look into this: http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/4996

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the uTube site of "iforce2d". Chris has a couple of GPS projects, which use a GPS and nRF24L01 transceivers to implement a "GPS tag" and he has a model car follow the tag. He also has a ground station with a pan and tilt and a camera following his quadcopter (drone). Lots of useful stuff there.